# How can I click an element even if another element is covering it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a button on a website but I get the error

`type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (455, 612). Other element would receive the click: <div style="height: 34px; width: 163.859px; z-index: 2147483647; cursor: pointer; top: 595px; left: 374.062px; position: fixed;"></div>`

I still want to click the button regardless of if it clicks the other element.

how can I do this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select element and use JavaScript to click it

```
selected_button = ...

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", selected_button)
```